# Soft keyboard hides edit text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

I'm create a login page and I have two normal credential edit text field,
the first one is for phone number and input type is number and it's ok,
here the problem with second edit text for password, I set input type to textPassword and I'm need to set text direction for both edit texts to RTL so I set gravity to right and when I set gravity to right just in Android 6.0.1 keyboard fill edit text (hide edit text field) and I can't see what I'm typing.

This is my xml code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.samanjafari.recycelerviewitemanimation.LoginActivity">

 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="forgot password"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How are you guys?"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fields_lyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="phone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fields_lyt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Android Manifest file, try adding the following attribute for your LoginActivity :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

or 
 `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

That will adjust the views so the keyboard doesn't hide them. There are different options for the mode. Have a look in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) and see which one suits your needs teh best.

Comment: i already use this attribute and work on other devices but not working only in two device (htc and asus with android 6.0.1).but also i change the keyboard using on htc and use default keyboard of device and work properly .. can this problem occur because the keyboard???

Comment: @arman could you post screenshots with the two different keyboards on your htc?

Comment: i tested it again and not work even in default keyboard,,, i dont know what should i do anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use Scrollview and set android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in child layout and other way is use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in specific activity tag in manifest